# Need help splitting a column in my DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, object, split, calculated-columns

I have a Python DataFrame "dt", one of the dt columns "betName" is filled with objects that sometimes have +/- numbers after the names. I'm trying to figure out how to separate "betName" into 2 columns "betName" & "line" where "betName" is just the name and "line" has the +/- number or regular number

Please see screenshots, thank you for helping!

[example of problem and desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bofaC.png)

[dt["betName"]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51FJz.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, post the code, or in your case, example data, as text so people can copy and paste it. Talking of code - what did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: Sorry, new here! Didn't know

I tried looping through each row a few different ways but couldn't get the numbers to extract correctly and then I tried different regex searches that kind of worked but couldn't quite get what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (**updated**) code:

```
df2=df['betName'].str.split(r' (?=[+-]\d{1,}\.?\d{,}?)', expand=True).astype('str')
```

**Explanation.** You can use `str.split` to split a text in the rows into 2 or more columns by regular expression:

```
  (?=[+-]\d{1,}\.?\d{,}?)
```

`' '` - Space char is the first.

`()` - Indicates the start and end of a group.

`?=` - Lookahead assertion. Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string.

`[+-]` - a set of characters. It will match + or -.

`\d{1,}` - `\d` is a digit from 0 to 9 with `{start, end}` number of digits. Here it means from 1 to any number: 1,200,4000 etc.

`\.?` - `\.` for a dot and `?` - 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding expression group or symbol.

**str.split(pattern=None, n=- 1, expand=False)**

`pattern` - string or regular expression to split on. If not specified, split on whitespace

`n` - number of splits in output. None, 0 and -1 will be interpreted as return all splits.

`expand` - expand the split strings into separate columns.

- `True` for placing splitted groups into different columns
- `False` for Series/Index lists of strings in a row.

by `.astype('str')` function you convert dataframe to string type.

**The output.**

[image: The output.]

Comment: This works great! And takes care of the St. issue with the Cardinals! Is there a way to keep the "+" when it shows up for certain cells? For example: Atlanta Braves +1.5 is outputting as 1.5 instead of +1.5

Thanks again!

Comment: try to add... expand=True).astype('str')

Comment: works awesome, was just a bug that first time..original code appears to be getting it done. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you explain to me what each segment of the code is doing? I'd like to fully understand how you came up with this

Comment: Of course, but I will be able  to do it in the evening. Please, kindly wait.

Comment: Here is the explanation. Please, do not forget to vote for the best answers.)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Added a split before doing the regex. This applies the regex only to the cell information that comes after the last white space.

I think you need to extract the bet information with a regular expression.

```
df["line"] = df["betName"].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1]).str.extract('([0-9.+-]+)')
```

Here's how the regex works - the () sets up a capture group, i.e. specifies what information you want to extract.

The stuff inside the square brackets is a character class, so here it matches any number from 0-9, + or - signs and a full stop.

Then plus sign after the square brackets mean match one or more repetitions of anything in the character class.

Comment: This works almost perfectly! Only error is with the St.Louis Cardinals, because of the "." it fills that corresponding cell with a "." instead of NaN or the number

Is there a way to filter out "St."??? Thank you so much

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Adding an updated solution...

Comment: Logic checks out I see what your trying to do...the updated line is throwing "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" any ideas?

Comment: ^^ fixed this by adding ")" at the end but now its throwing "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'"

Comment: Hmm can you update your question with some sample data in the question? This works for me in a python interpreter:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'betName': ['St. Louis +1.5']})
df["line"] = df["betName"].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1]).str.extract('([0-9.+-]+)')

Comment: Ah just figured out that error - I think something maybe went wrong in the copy and paste? Make sure you close the brackets here apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1]), otherwise it will try and access a str attribute from the string the lambda function returns.

Comment: Ahh got it, thank you so much for your help!